# Convert bytes to string while replacing SOH character

Tags: python-3.x, fix-protocol

Using python 3.6. I have a bytes array that is coming over a socket (a FIX message) that contains hex character 1, start of header, as a delimiter. The raw bytes look like

```
b'8=FIX.4.4\x019=65\x0135=0\x0152=20220809-21:37:06.893\x0149=TRADEWEB\x0156=ABFIXREPO\x01347=UTF-8\x0110=045\x01'
```

I want to store this bytes array to a file for logging. I have seen FIX messages where this delimiter is converted to `^A` control character. The final string I would like to have is -

```
8=FIX.4.4^A9=65^A35=0^A52=20220809-21:37:06.893^A49=TRADEWEB^A56=ABFIXREPO^A347=UTF-8^A10=045^A
```

I have tried various different ways to achieve this but could not, for example, tried `repr(bytes)` and `(ord(b) in bytes)`.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing this is by splitting the original decoded byte array , and insert control character using a loop.

```
data = b'8=FIX.4.4\x019=65\x0135=0\x0152=20220809-21:37:06.893\x0149=TRADEWEB\x0156=ABFIXREPO\x01347=UTF-8\x0110=045\x01'
data = data.decode().split("\x01")
print(data)
ctl_char = "^A"
string =""
for i in data:
    string+=i
    string+=ctl_char
print(string)
```

Please note there can be a better way of doing it.